# Using a loop to generate and redirect tar output to new directory tree, how do i match the original directory tree structure, under a new root?

Tags: linux, bash, loops, scripting, tar

I am not certain how to ask this question, but... I am attempting to alter my tar backup script so that each sub-directory recreates and is then stored in a separate directory in my backup file/folder system. For example:

```
/mnt/foo/old_directory_tree/{folder1..folder6} > /mnt/bar/new_directory_tree/{folder1..folder6}.tar.gz
```

My loop will grab each sub-directory and print out each sub-directory in my generated log file, but I am stuck as how to use that loop function to generate and save the tar file for each sub-directory separately.

I do have an older version of a backup script that uses a separate script for each individual folder in order to accomplish this, but I am trying to use a loop instead.

```
SOURCE=/mnt/foo/
TAR=/mnt/bar/FooBackups/Daily/Backups/$TODAY/Daily.Backup.$TODAY.tar.gz


for p in $(find $SOURCE* -maxdepth 0 -type d); do
 echo "Backing up the following files in directory "$SOURCE "at " $(date "+%T") ":" >> $LOGS  
 echo $p >> $LOGS
 echo "" >> $LOGS
 echo "" >> $LOGS
 sleep 1

 echo "" >> $LOGS
 echo "" >> $LOGS

 echo "Full Daily backup of $p started at $(date)" >> $LOGS 
 tar --ignore-failed-read -I pigz -cvp -f $TAR --listed-incremental=$SNAR $p >> \
 $LOGS 2>&1 && echo "Full Daily backup of $p completed successfully at $(date)" >> \
 $LOGS || echo "Full Daily backup of $p completed with error at $(date)." >> \
 $LOGS &
 echo "" >> $LOGS
 echo "" >> $LOGS
done
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `TAR` does not change in your loop so you are overwriting the same file every time

Comment: Its an incremental backup that updates each night. There is a different loop that generates a separate snar file each time the cron job runs.

Comment: The `tar` command lets you select directories when you extract. Why not put everything into one tar file with `cd /mnt && tar -cvp -f $TAR <options…> foo`? Is it a disk space issue?

Comment: That was my original plan, but I'm trying to keep it in line with the existing format. I will keep it as is with one tar file if I need to.

Comment: Are you trying to store tar files in a directory structure that parallels the original structure ?  Or are you trying to do something like ... cd ${source_root} ; tar cf - . | ( cd ${mirror_root} ; tar xvpf - ) ... ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to store in a directory that parallels the original. Thank you for the verbage. The existing format is structured that way and I am keeping that format.